# Add New View to Layout Upon Button Click in Android

Tags: android, view

I'm developing a Scorekeeping Application for the card game "Spades".

Upon a button click at the end of each hand, I would like to store some information about the hand into a TextView and display all of the hand histories in a ScrollView.

How can I modify an .XML layout or otherwise add a new TextView to a layout in code?

I have tried...

```
public static LinearLayout gamehistory;

gamehistory = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gamehistory);


public void setClickListener1(){

lockwagersButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {

setContentView(R.layout.results_layout);

gameHistory.addView(new TextView(...));       //  I can't get this to work 
            ...
```

Thanks!
-K.H.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

following code add textview onclick:

```
public class ViewOnClick extends Activity {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
    LinearLayout ll;
    static int i;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll);
        layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
        (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView view = new TextView(ViewOnClick.this);             
                view.setText(++i+" view");
                ll.addView(view, layoutParams); 

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That's interesting.  It works for one click, but only one click.



gamehistory = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gamehistory);
              
layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

TextView handHistory = new TextView(ScoreboardActivity.this);
              
handHistory.setText("Test");
                 
gamehistory.addView(handHistory, layoutParams);

Comment: I've determined that it just keeps overwriting the old view.

Comment: It is not overwriting.  U r using LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT instead of that use LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT

Comment: But Fill_PARENT is for the width, which is what I want.  I used WRAP_CONTENT for the height so that I can add more TextView below it.  Here is my XML:

<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/gamehistory"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</LinearLayout>      
</ScrollView>

I'm trying to add to the LinearLayout "gamehistory" inside of the ScrollView.

Comment: P.S.  I don't know why it won't display properly in the comment box.

Comment: I tried with WRAP_CONTENT.  Still displays only 1 new TextView.

Comment: I don't know your problem. It is straightforward I have put code below.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <RelativeLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <Button 
            android:text="Button01" 
            android:id="@+id/Button01" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>  
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_below="@id/Button01"
            android:id="@+id/scrollview" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/gamehistory" 
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
            </LinearLayout> 

        </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

```
public class Scrollview1 extends Activity {
    ScrollView scrollview;
    LinearLayout  linearLayout;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
    static int i;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        scrollview = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.gamehistory);
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
        (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView view = new TextView(Scrollview1.this);             
                view.setText(++i+" view");
                linearLayout.addView(view, layoutParams); 
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it has to do with my ad-hoc way of solving this other problem I've been having.  Maybe you can help me with this:

I have two buttons in two different layouts.  I switch between the layouts within one Scoreboard Activity.  Am I able to define onClickListeners for both of them in the onCreate() method for the activity?  It seems like I can't, so whenever I switch the layout using setContentView I have to activate the proper click listener.  This means I set the click listener each time and I think this is why I am "overwriting" my addView.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase.  Within an activity called ScoreboardActivity I switch between two layouts, scoreboard_layout.xml and results_layout.xml in order to take wagers and then take results.  scoreboard_layout.xml has a button called "lock wagers" and results_layout.xml has a button called "lock results".  But I can't set both of their click listeners in onCreate() for ScoreboardActivity because apparently you can only set a click listener for a button in the current content view setContentView(...).  So I have to toggle back and forth resetting the click listeners in recursion.

Comment: Might this have something to do with why I can't get the new TextView to NOT overwrite the old one and instead add on?

Comment: I've added the outline of my code above as an "answer" and shown how I used what you gave me in saveHandHistory()

Comment: why you are not using different activities for result layout and scoreboard layout?

Comment: Maybe I should, but I didn't think it would make a difference for this error.

Comment: I think I will try that.  How do you change between Activities within one tab?

Comment: I decided to just add the hand history to its own tab.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setClickListeners() 
{
    lockwagersButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
         // Do Stuff
        lockresultsButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                        calculateScores();                  
                        setContentView(R.layout.scoreboard_layout);
                        SettingsActivity.currentdealer.getNextDealer();
                        setSpinners1();
                        findDisplays();
                        setPlayerNamesScoreboard();
                        lockwagersButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lockwagers);
                        displayScores();
                        checkForWinner();
                        saveHandHistory();
                        setClickListeners(); // This is the recursion <------
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Based on what you gave me

```
public void saveHandHistory(){
    scrollview = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView1);
    gamehistory = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gamehistory); 
    layoutparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TextView handHistory = new TextView(ScoreboardActivity.this);
    handHistory.setText("Hand History Will Go Here");
    gamehistory.addView(handHistory, layoutparams);
}
```