# How do I implement a pop in EditText field on Android?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I was wondering if someone could tell me how I would go about implementing this EditText pop-in shown in the second image here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is probably the [`AdapterView` pattern](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html). There's an underlying [`Adapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) listing each course, and you override the `getView()` method to display whatever you want for each item in the `Adapter`. You could display an `EditText` for new, uninitialized courses, and a standard `TextView` otherwise. This is often accomplished by extending [`ArrayAdapter<Course>`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html), for example.

Comment: What causes this *pop in* to appear?

Comment: @Phil Clicking the + button at the top causes it to appear

Answer (score 0):

You mean, when you click on a + button, a new view of EditText will add to the layout. try this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733021/add-new-view-to-layout-upon-button-click-in-android) it may help you.

Comment: so should I programmatically add in the views?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this. i answered a similar question with a solution by implementing a `ListView` here:

[How to display item after clicked the button in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658682/how-to-display-item-after-clicked-the-button-in-eclipse/13660943#13660943)