# How to display item after clicked the button in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, button

In my apps.. the user can key in there expenses based on category, if they have more than 1 category to key in, there have a button to allow user to click on to display another set of the category (red rectangle box content) in the same page.

Any method can do this?

Thank you very much.

[image: screenshot of expenses page]

my layout xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f8f9fe"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<include layout="@layout/actionbar_layout" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recordExpenses"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dip"
        android:text="@string/expensesRecord"
        android:textColor="#ff29549f"
        android:textSize="25dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recordDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.59"
        android:text="@string/date"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/recordDaySpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.84"
        android:entries="@array/daySpinner" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recordCategory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/category"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/recordCategorySpinner"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:entries="@array/categorySpinner"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recordRM"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        android:text="@string/rm"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="99dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/recordAddCategory"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/addCategory" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/total"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/total"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/balance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/balance"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/back" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/recordSaveButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/save" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your code so that I an answer from it, and how this question is related to eclipse ?

Comment: the code has been added..
i am using eclipse to develop my apps..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it took me a while but i think i finally got what you wanted. Personally I think the way you'd do this is by implementing that section as a `listView` or a dynamic table layout. I did a small mock-up with a listView as i'd think it'd be less cumbersome to work with.

The main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private CustomAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button btnAdd_category = (Button) findViewById(R.id.recordAddCategory);
        btnAdd_category.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.addRow();
            }
        });
    }
```

The custom adapter for the listView

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    int rowCount = 1;
    private LayoutInflater inflator;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
        super();
        inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return rowCount;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int postion, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);            
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    public void addRow() {
        rowCount++;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the entire mechanism is hinged on the `getCount()` method. when you add or decrease the number it returns, it tells the adapter how many rows you want inflated. To modify it we made a method called `addRow()`. The rest should be self-explanatory. The `row` xml here being inflated would simply be that red boxed linearLayout that you want repeated upon pressing the button. I'd recommend putting the whole page in a `ScrollView` because you're gonna need it if the additional rows make views go out of bounds.

---

Moreover, this has nothing to do with your question, but i think you reconsider your xml layout. in general using more viewGroups (`LinearLayout`, etc.) than you can manage without is much less efficient. Perhaps, if it'd please you, try taking `RelativeLayout` for a spin or find a way to box everything in one `LinearLayout`, as it was designed for stacking multiple rows of views much like you have, without extra containers.