# adding ListView items by clicking on a button

Tags: android, listview, button, user-input

after some days of trying, searching and again trying i want to ask u guys for help.

I want to fill a ListView by clicking on a button with random user input items.

here is a example picture of my activity_main.xml

http://s1.directupload.net/file/d/3109/x6qnnj5s_png.htm

i Tried severel code snippets from here and other sites but every time my Virtual device says The application test_1 (process com.example.test_1) has stopped unexpectedly. Pleasy try again.

my current code is:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/tPlanView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/addTplan" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addTplan"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Button" />
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textIn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textOut"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"

    />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

/** Items entered by the user is stored in this ArrayList variable */
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

/** Declaring an ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /** Setting a custom layout for the list activity */
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /** Reference to the button of the layout main.xml */
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addTplan);

    /** Defining the ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    /** Setting the event listener for the add button */
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textIn);
            list.add(edit.getText().toString());
            edit.setText("");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

    /** Setting the adapter to the ListView */
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

im glad for any help.
thanks in advance allready :-)

**------- UPDATE ------**

logcat

```
    12-19 22:45:02.854: D/AndroidRuntime(330): Shutting down VM
12-19 22:45:02.854: W/dalvikvm(330): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
12-19 22:45:02.864: E/AndroidRuntime(330): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-19 22:45:02.864: E/AndroidRuntime(330): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ de.example.test_1test_1/ de.example.test_1.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
12-19 22:45:02.864: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
12-19 22:45:02.864: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-19 22:45:02.864: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-19 22:45:02.864: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-19 22:45:02.864: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-19 22:45:02.864: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-19 22:45:02.864: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-19 22:45:02.864: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-19 22:45:02.864: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-19 22:45:02.864: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-19 22:45:02.864: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-19 22:45:02.864: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-19 22:45:02.864: E/AndroidRuntime(330): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
12-19 22:45:02.864: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
12-19 22:45:02.864: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:210)
12-19 22:45:02.864: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
12-19 22:45:02.864: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at  de.example.test_1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
12-19 22:45:02.864: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-19 22:45:02.864: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-19 22:45:02.864: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  ... 11 more
12-19 22:45:05.964: I/Process(330): Sending signal. PID: 330 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can you please post your logcat?

Comment: thank you for that fast responding. logcat added in question

Comment: You're using a ListActivity with a default ArrayAdapter, but IIRC I think you should define your own custom ArrayAdapter that inflates your list_item.xml that holds your TextView and EditText.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're going to use `extends ListActivity` then the `ListView` in your main layout must be written like this with this id:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list" <---------
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/addTplan" >
</ListView>
```

As for the main question inquiry, maybe you'd find this answer to the following question useful as it covers the same topic.

[How to display item after clicked the button in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658682/how-to-display-item-after-clicked-the-button-in-eclipse/13660943#13660943)

Answer (score 1):

change

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/tPlanView"
```

to

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
```